# angular JS custom directive not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services

```
app.directive("myData", function()
{
    return {
        templateUrl: '/my-data.html'
    };

});
my-data.html file code

<tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
    <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.gender | uppercase }}</td>
    <td>{{employee.salary | currency : '$'}}</td>
</tr>


<body ng-app="DemoAngular">
    <div ng-controller="AngularController">

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <my-data></my-data>
</tbody>
        </table>


    </div>
</body>
```

custom directive reg.,directive template html file assign.,
calling custom directive in table body., also added scripts file location in 
 header. 
nothing is populating /not working ..
need help Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myData` won't be recognized in `table` element. you can change your directive with `restrict: 'A'` and use it in your template as below:

```
<table>
  <thead>
  ...
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr my-data></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**UPD:**

add `replace:true` to your directive.

demo [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BAHhxB7ClQfh0ffCkFgr?p=preview).

Comment: app.service('AngularService', function ($http, $log) {

    //var customservice = {};

    this.getalldata = function (cb) {

        $http({

            method: 'GET',
            url: 'WebService/EmployeeService.asmx/GetAllEmployee'
        }).then(function (response) {
            cb(response.data);


        }, function (reason) {
            $log.log("error");
        })

    };

    // return customservice;
});

Comment: i tried as you mentioned but directive not showing anything  1.i have html file 2. control file 3. main html in which i am adding tag

Comment: @cshah sorry for the late response,  I have updated my answer and add a runnable example for you.

Comment: i have added directive like below using TempleteURL ..app.directive('myData', function ()
{
    console.log('in');
    return {

        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'my-data.html'
        
    };

});...

Comment: .now 'my-data.html' file having tags ...        <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
            <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.name}}</td>-
            <td>{{employee.gender | uppercase }}</td>
            <td>{{employee.salary | currency : '$'}}</td>
        </tr>
calling service to fill data service returning data which is good .but my screen is still empty only table headers are cming.....any clue....i checked your code seems diff is i am using TemplateURL.?

Comment: @cshah they are basically the same. wait a moment, I'll change the example to templateUrl

Comment: @cshah check the example again, I have change to templeteUrl for you, and it work fine there.

Comment: not sure why same thing not working for me. 
 this is my control and service ....app.controller('AngularController', function ($scope, AngularService) {
     AngularService.getalldata(function (cb) {
         
         $scope.employees = cb;
       //  console.log(cb);
     });
     
     });.....

Comment: app.service('AngularService', function ($http, $log) {

    //var customservice = {};

    this.getalldata = function (cb) {

        $http({

            method: 'GET',
            url: 'WebService/EmployeeService.asmx/GetAllEmployee'
        }).then(function (response) {
            cb(response.data);


        }, function (reason) {
            $log.log("error");
        })

    };

    // return customservice;
});

Comment: @cshah are you sure you got data from your service?

Comment: @cshah and check is there any error in your console.

Comment: <tbody>
                <tr my-data>
                </tr>

            </tbody>   for 'my-data' i am getting waring like 'unknown attribute' ...

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) in my-data.html

Comment: one more i can see from angular.min.js ---Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$compile/tpload?p0=my-data.html&p1=404&p2=Not%20Found
    at angular.min.js:6
    at angular.min.js:159
    at angular.min.js:134
    at m.$digest (angular.min.js:145)
    at m.$apply (angular.min.js:149)
    at l (angular.min.js:102)
    at XMLHttpRequest.A.onload (angular.min.js:107)

Comment: @cshah so you cannot reach your server, we are done with front-end, you have to checkout your server part now.

Comment: I found issue ..but tx for your help and inputs so far...i found below issue  i loaded scripts files in wrong order....it was like controler.js then angular.min..js so i changed order <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Controller.js"></script>...and now its works for me